# Is infinite boolean algebra atomless?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

I got two questions:

1) Does there exist an infinite Boolean algebra which contains an atom?

I answered yes.

2) Does there exist an infinite Boolean algebra B such that for every b contained in B there is an atom a contained in B with a is smaller or equal than b?

I answered no.

I just cannot figure out what's the difference between these two questions.
Can someone help please?

Comment: For #2, are you sure that whoever gave you this problem didn't mean "for every nonzero $b$ contained in $B$"?  For #1, you answered yes - what was your example? Is it also an example for #2?

Comment: For question 2, it has been specified that b is nonzero.

Comment: For question 1, I just guessed the answer...I just didn't understand well this part.

Comment: The topic of infinite atomless Boolean algebras [has come up here previously](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/290669/non-isomorphic-countable-boolean-algebras).  In large part the meaningful parts of this Question were settled there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: I see from the comments that $b$ in part 2 is restricted so that it *can't* be the least element of $B$. That's fairly important information, and changes my answer.

One hint will apply to both parts equally well. The most familiar form of a Boolean Algebra is the power set of a set. Consider the power set of an infinite set to answer both of your questions.

**Added**: Your example--letting $B$ be the power set of the natural numbers--works as an example for both. As you pointed out, its atoms are precisely the singleton subsets of the natural numbers. Hence, $B$ has an atom--in fact, infinitely-many, but it has at least one, which is what matters--and so the answer to Question 1 is "yes." On the other hand, given any non-least element $b$ of $B$ (that is, any non-empty subset of the natural numbers), there is at least one atom less than or equal to it--for example, the singleton containing only the least element of $b$.  Hence, the answer to Question 2 is also "yes."

Comment: Using your hint for question 2, I assumed that there is no such infinite boolean algebra...Right?

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot understand the hint...

Comment: Well, you can assume it (correctly). However, you *should* be able to *prove* it. In fact, you should be able to show that even if we get rid of the word "infinite," there is *still* no Boolean algebra that satisfies the given condition (that is, even if $B$ is finite, consider what happens if $b$ is the least element of $B$).

Comment: If I take the powerset of the the natural numbers. I would say that there exist more than one atoms beecause the number of singletons(atoms) are also infinite. So, the answer would be no for Q1.

Comment: For question 2, I think of the Lindenbaum-Tarski algebra with a set of infinite variables. Since, the number of atoms is 2 to the n. And the number of elements is 2 to the number of atoms. So, there are more elements than atoms. The answer is no.

Comment: Not at all. The answer is "yes" for both--"an atom" means "at least one atom," not "exactly one atom." Also, don't forget that a single atom can lie below multiple elements. Again, try considering the power set of the naturals. What are the atoms there? Given a non-empty subset of the naturals, can you find an atom below (or equal to) it?

Comment: Given a subset of the naturals, the atom is the singleton that appear in this subset...Right?

Comment: I think again for Question 2. Why was I wrong?

Comment: I have expanded my answer to provide a more elaborate explanation. As for the problem with your reasoning for question 2: if a Boolean algebra has $2$ or more atoms, there will ***always*** be more elements than atoms, regardless of whether each non-least, non-atomic element lies over some atom.

Comment: Ok!!I reread my class notes and I think I understand why the answer for question 2 is yes, but I still want to hear your explanation for sure!! Thank you!

Comment: Let me make a slight correction to my last comment: Given ***any*** Boolean algebra, there will ***always*** be more elements than atoms.

Comment: @CameronBuie the wording of the question is throwing me off here. It reads,

 "Does there exist an infinite Boolean algebra B such that
for every nonzero b ∈ B there is an atom a ∈ B with a ≤ b?"

If we consider the power set of natural numbers as our Boolean Algebra, then there are infinitely many atoms. How then, can we claim there is "an atom" such that a ≤ b, if we take b to be another atom?

Comment: @User38: The kicker is in the phrasing. We are not saying "there is an atom $a\in B$ such that for every non-zero element $b\in B$...." That would mean that there is **one** $a$ that works for **every** non-zero $b\in B,$ which, as you point out, is clearly not the case. Rather, we are saying that "for every non-zero $b\in B,$ there is an atom $a\in B$ such that...." This means that, regardless of any particular choice of a non-zero $b\in B,$ we can find some $a\in B$ such that.... (cont'd)

Comment: For another (perhaps clearer) example: for every $b\in\Bbb R,$ there exists some $a\in\Bbb R$ such that $a<b.$ This doesn't mean that there is an $a\in\Bbb R$ less than every $a\in\Bbb R$. If that were true, then we would have $a<a,$ which is nonsense! Instead, we mean that, for any given $b\in\Bbb R,$ there is some $a\in\Bbb R$ such that $a<b.$ That is certainly true--just put $a=b-1$.

Comment: Back to the original phrasing, and the example of the power set of the natural numbers, take any non-zero $b\in B.$ Since $b$ is non-zero, then there is some $n\in b.$ Put $a=\{n\}.$ Then $a$ is an atom of $B$ and $a\le b,$ as desired.

Comment: @CameronBuie Ohh!! I finally understand now. Thanks so much! We had that question on assignment a while back and I never understood why I got it wrong..

Comment: @User38: Glad I could help!